# Using sympy function "solve" to solve equation that includes values from PYroMat

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to find a solution for equation that calculates ideal combustion temperature `t_spal` to achieve desired enthalpy `h_spal`. All thermodynamic calculation works except when I try to solve the equation with `solve` it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Pyromat output is *numpy.ndarray* so I tried to convert it into float but it doesn't help. I also tried to use `solveset` but it also doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import pyromat as pm
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

pm.config['unit_temperature'] = 'C'

CO2 = pm.get('ig.CO2')
H2O = pm.get('ig.H2O')
O2 = pm.get('ig.O2')
N2 = pm.get('ig.N2')

w_CO2 = 0.135 #-
w_H2O = 0.074 #-
w_O2 = 0.103 #-
w_N2 = 0.688 #-

h_spal = 1361 #kJ/kg

t_v = 25 #°C

t_spal = Symbol('t_spal') #°C
solve((w_CO2*(CO2.h(T=t_spal)-CO2.h(T=t_v)) + w_H2O*(H2O.h(T=t_spal)-H2O.h(T=t_v)) + w_O2*(O2.h(T=t_spal)-O2.h(T=t_v)) + w_N2*(N2.h(T=t_spal)-N2.h(T=t_v))-h_spal),t_spal)
```

Is it even possible to have a part of a module inside `solve` function? When I was searching through similiar posts I noticed that `sympy.solve` had the same type of error when using functions from `math` module.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `solve` function. You can't use a symbol like `t_spal` in something like `CO2.h(T=t_spal)`.

Comment: It's bad programming practice to pass a large expression to a function like `solve`.  Hint, if your code produces a horizontal scroll window in the SO format, it probably is too long.  Create that expression in smaller steps.  That way, if you do  get errors you can identify exactly where.  Remember, in Python, function arguments are evaluated BEFORE they are passed to the function.